# Menu with fixed top and relative left

Tags: css

The facebook appcenter menu has fixed top and relative left. It looks like it's updating from javascript. Does anyone know how to do that? Or if there is a plugin out there like this? I can't for the life of me find it.

http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/?from_bookmark=1

Comment: Not enough detail as to what you want exactly. Try using some sample code (jsfiddle is good for this) of your attempts to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: The link shows the exact menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position: fixed

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed

This fiddle demonstrates a fixed element with a dynamic "left" value using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/Tws2W/.

Code of interest:

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{
  $('#fixed').css('left', Math.max(($(window).width() - 400), 0) + 'px');
});​
```

Comment: This does not allow an element to be relatively left placed